# Finite CMRR even with ideal tail current source (body effect)

Tags: differential, common-mode, differential-amplifier

In Razavi's Design of Analog CMOS Integrated Circuits 2nd edition page 123, the diff-pair below is included with a comment about how even if the tail current source is infinite, if the transistor pair do not have the same \$g_{mb}\$ then a change in the input CM level will produce a differential output voltage.

I'm not sure how this is possible. Thinking from a large signal perspective: assume that with some initial input common mode there are some bias currents \$I_{D1} \neq I_{D2}\$, \$I_{D1}+I_{D2}=I_{SS}\$. If there is an increase in the input common mode, then the source node increases (otherwise the \$V_{GS}\$ of both transistors increases and so both want to conduct more current, but that's not possible since then \$I_{D1}+I_{D2} \geq I_{SS}\$), thus the drain currents don't change as a result of \$V_{GS}\$.

Razavi says that if \$g_{mb1} \neq g_{mb2}\$ then there will be a change in the drain currents. When \$V_P\$ goes up, then yes the \$V_{BS}\$ of each transistor changes by the same amount and since the body transconductances are different the current change in each branch should be different. But for both NMOS devices the decrease in \$V_{BS}\$ makes *both* devices want to *decrease* their currents, which shouldn't be possible if their sum is fixed, just like in the case above. Am I missing something that makes this case different?

[image]

Comment: Are ID1 and ID2 really current sources, or are they assumed to go to output devices with an element of constant voltage about them? The change in input CM changes Vds and Vdg, perhaps not in the same way in the two devices?

Comment: @Neil_UK I think the only ideal current source here is Iss. What also confuses me is that Razavi carries out the earlier analysis showing that infinite Iss output impedance guarantees infinite CMRR assuming no channel modulation or body effect. Then as I describe in the post he says actually body effect would mean finite CMRR. Like you say, Vds could change but that only matters for lambda > 0. Also, not sure what the relevance of Vdg is?